# The all-powerful "to have"

Tags: grammar, etymology, tenses

"To have" seems to fill a lot of different needs in the English language, apart from its literal meaning of possessing something.

It's an integral part of perfect and perfect progressive verb tenses: *I have run*, *I had run*, *I had been running*, *I will have been running*, etc.

It also indicates need: *I have to eat*, *I had to leave* (or is this another tense of some sort?)

This leads to forms of *to have* showing up multiple times in a sentence, and yet it makes perfect sense: *I had to have had at least three apples.*

How did this come about?  I've noticed *avoir* and *tener* also have these same uses in French & Spanish, respectively.

Comment: Heh, reminds me of John Perry's funny essay [ *On Becoming Bilingual* ](http://www.structuredprocrastination.com/light/biling.php): “Consider, for example, the word "get" and the associated simple straightforward idea. […] "I got out of bed, got the paper, got myself some breakfast, got some coffee, and began to get dressed and to get ready for work. I got in the car, got to the office, and got to work. I got a lot done, and still had time to get some money at the bank and get a sandwich at the deli for lunch." To describe my morning in French I would need at least half a dozen verbs…”

Comment: "Got in the car" -- Now that really is weird when you think about it

Comment: Note: "haber" is the verb you're looking for in Spanish. "tener" means to hold/own/posess. "haber" is the one used as the auxiliary verb.

Comment: Also, +1. I like historical questions such as these. :)

Comment: @Noldorin: Can't you say `tengo que ir` ("I have to go") to indicate need?  Though I do realize now that's the only use I'm familiar with, and maybe not to indicate tense. (I'm better versed in French than Spanish)

Comment: @keithjgrant: You can indeed, but that's a special construction in Spanish (as in English). I suppose your question really brings up two points, one about the auxiliary verb (which I addressed) and the other about the much narrower usage of expressing need ("I have to ..."). As a note, "I have run" = "he corrido" in Spanish, "I had run" = "habia corrido" (both using "haber"). It's an odd language in that it has two different verbs for "to have"!

Comment: @Noldorin: Oh well, if there are already two verbs for "to be", why not have two verbs for "to have" as well... On a second thought, disregard that; I don't think we should be calling Spanish "odd" *in the context of this particular question*. I mean, the whole point here is that English uses "to have" as a one-size-fits-all solution, while Spanish came up as an example of a language where different verbs are used in different situations. If anyone's odd here, that's English.

Comment: @RegDwight: I mean odd purely in the sense of unusual. All other European languages I have studied (Latin, French, Spanish) have one verb for "to have". Spanish and Italian have two verbs for "to be", while Classical Latin and French only have one. There's no doubting it's an exception to the 'rule'. I think it's quite a fair comment to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a little side note: *To have* in English (as in other languages such as French, Spanish, and Italian) is an auxiliary verb most commonly used for forming the simple/continuous perfect and pluperfect tenses, among others. The other mean example of an auxiliary verb is *to be*, which is used very similarly in other European languages. (*To do* is another, though rather more specific to English perhaps.)

As far as the history/origin of auxiliary verbs goes, in particular *to have*, I'm afraid I don't know - this is rather a specialty of a historical linguist. However, I can tell you that the use of auxiliary/compound verbs (certainly in forming various past tenses) was *not* apparent in Classical Latin, which utilized only word suffixes for changing verb mood and tense. Since however the use of the auxiliary to form the perfect and pluperfect tenses is present in the three main Romance languages of today (French, Spanish, Italian), this suggests that the origin most likely lies with Vulgar Latin, i.e. the vernacular tongue spoken during the late period of the Roman Empire and early Middle Ages, which evolved into the various modern Romance languages. Whether English developed this compound verb form (auxiliary + principal verb) independently via a Germanic route, I do not know, but it is quite possible that it inherited this form from Norman French.

Apologies for the bit of speculation, hopefully it provides some useful information, or perhaps at least a starting point for further research!

Answer (score 0):

`Have` is one of the verbs of being. The verbs of being are:

- Be
- Am
- Is
- Are
- Was
- Were
- Being
- Been
- Have
- Has
- Had
- Shall
- Will
- May
- Can
- Might
- Could
- Should
- Would

The verbs of being are "special" in that they can exist as helper verbs when placed in a supporting position (I have gone to the show), and also as primary verbs when placed in a more normal position: (I have measles).

All of the verbs of being have a multitude of uses in English because they are used to convey state and changes of state, which exist quite often in real world scenarios.